# OpenOffice won't execute formula

Tags: openoffice

I'm running OpenOffice 4.1.1 on OSX. I typed a formula into a cell, but the cell shows the raw formula, not the result of executing the formula. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? What does this have to do with Unix & Linux?

Comment: @jordanm Well, it's an application that runs on Linux, which we list as on-topic

Comment: If you would provide us with the formula, we might be able to point out that you forgot an initial `=` or other error that you might have made there. As the question is now your machine might even be frozen at the moment you finished typing a correct formula. So please give us more relevant details by updating the question. At least the formula, preferably also the cells contents the formula refers to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prefix the formula with one of the following symbols: `=`, `+`, or `-`. Anything else is treated as plain text. For example, if you want to compute 2 + 2, you can use `=2+2` or `+2+2`, but `2+2` is just a plain string. This is explained in the [OpenOffice wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Creating_formulas).

<sub>(As a sidenote, strings have their own prefix, `'`, so `'=2+2` would be the string `=2+2`)</sub>